# How to download image in android?

Tags: java, android, image, download

I have an image to the right and a button "download" to the left. the image is from my drawable. now,when i try to click the download i want to put the image to my sdcard downloads. Please help me i only see about download in url. is there other solution for this . Thanks

```
public class ImageDownloader {

public void download(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
        task.execute(url);
    }
}

 /* class BitmapDownloaderTask, see below */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get your Bitmap. You can already have it as an object Bitmap, or you can try to get it from the `ImageView` such as:

```
 BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ImageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Then you must get to directory (a File object) from SD Card such as:

```
File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Next, create your specific file for image storage:

```
 File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test.png");
```

After that, you just have to write the Bitmap such as:

```
boolean success = false;

// Encode the file as a PNG image.
FileOutputStream outStream;
try {

    outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
    success = true;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Finally, just deal with the boolean result if needed. Such as:

```
if (success) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Don't forget to add the following permission in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```